# Accounting: Should a fee on an amount payable be applied in AR or AP account?

Tags: accounting, double-entry

An application I'm building has a simplistic double-entry accounting component to it to keep track of funds passed owed to various parties. I'm unclear on how certain entries should be applied. Take the following example:

- A soccer referee works a game and earns $50 from the league
- He then fails to submit a game report within the time limit and is assessed a $10 late fee.
- The referee should have a total of $40 owed to him.

From the referee's perspective, should both of those transactions affect his Sales and AR accounts?

- $50 CREDIT to Sales account
- $50 DEBIT to AR account
- $10 DEBIT to Sales account
- $10 CREDIT to AR account

Or would the first be Sales/AR and the other be Expenses/AP?

- $50 CREDIT to Sales account
- $50 DEBIT to AR account
- $10 DEBIT to Expenses account
- $10 CREDIT to AP account

Or should it be something else completely?

Answer (score 5):

The actual "sale" in this case was for $50, so you should credit the full $50 to the Sales Account.

To balance this entry you would make two opposite postings.  A $10 debit to the expenses account and a $40 debit to Accounts Receivable.

This ensures the full $50 payment is balanced on both sides, whilst only $40 is expected to be received.  The $10 is filed as an expense.

You seem to be trying to split this up into two transactions, each with only a single debit and a single credit.  Whilst there's nothing wrong with that, you would end up with two Sales credits, one for $40 and the other for $10 - which doesn't really reflect what happened.

Comment: Yes, of coures the "sale" is $50. My mistake, I'll update the question. Thanks for your help!